# Javascript: Why is a constructor's __proto__ property Empty() { }?

Tags: javascript

I created a simple constructor like:

```
function Car() { 
    this.noTires = 5;
}
```

`Car.__proto__` prints out `Empty() {}`

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

protoype is a property of every constructor
It is an object which is a prototype of a new instance.
you can define it something like this.

```
Car.prototype.name="Audi";
Car.prototype.model="A4";
```

making a constructor does not mean making a prototype.
Prototypes are used when  we want to make instances pointeng to the same block
eg.

```
function Person(){
}

Person.prototype.name = "detailer";
Person.prototype.age = 17;
Person.prototype.job ="Developer"
Person.prototype.sayName = function(){
 alert(this.name);
};

var person1 = new Person();
var person2 = new Person();

person1.name = "lakshay";
alert(person1.name); //lakshay - from instance
alert(person2.name); //detailer - from prototype
```